# cpan modules search from the command line?

Tags: perl, cpan

If I'm not wrong the first step to start with the command line with cpan is next

```
# perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

but I don't know what I should do for looking a module, can you help me, what should I write to find next module?:

http://search.cpan.org/~jesus/Spread-3.17.4.4/Spread.pm

Answer (score 3):

From the CPAN shell:

```
cpan> m Module::Name
```

This will search for a module.

[Source](http://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN.html#CPAN::shell%28%5B$prompt,-$command%5D%29-Starting-Interactive-Mode)

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong about the fact that `perl -MCPAN -e shell` starts the CPAN shell, but usually, you'll have also `cpan` available, which is much less typing and will spawn the CPAN shell as well.
And if you only want to install the module **Spread** you can simply type this on the command line (thus without starting the CPAN shell):

`cpan Spread`

and that will be all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MCPAN -e 'print Dumper([CPAN::Shell->expandany("Spread")])'
```